# How can I access calendars on my Mac with Java?

Tags: java, macos

I want to read data stored locally by the Apple Calendar app on my Mac (12.1 Monterey).
The data is stored in subdirectories of `~/Library/Calendars/` with one subdirectory per calendar.
The problem: When I try to get a list of files from there, Java returns `null`:

```
String userHomeDir = System.getProperty("user.home");
File calendarRoot = new File(userHomeDir + "/Library/Calendars/");
File[] calendars = calendarRoot.listFiles();
System.out.println("Number of files: " + calendars.length); // NPE thrown here
```

File permissions are as follows:

- ~/Library: drwx------+ (owner: my user)
- ~/Library/Calendars: drwxr-xr-x@ (owner: my user)

Listing files in `Library` works fine.

How can I access that folder?

Comment: Try using Files class instead: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html.

Comment: As pringi says. This should give you an exception that tells you what the problem is. Try `Files.list(Path.of(System.getProperty("user.dir"), "Library", "Calendars")).forEach(System.out::println)`

Comment: Did you actually verify that `System.getProperty("user.home")` returns anything?

Comment: @RealSkeptic `System.getProperty("user.home")` works nicely. @k314159 That line throws `java.nio.file.FileSystemException: /Users/(myusername)/Library/Calendars: Operation not permitted`

Comment: Looks like you have extended attributes on your Calendars folder. Use `ls -l@` to show them, and see if you find anything relevant.

Comment: @RealSkeptic Thanks, that pointed me in the right direction, as seeing "com.apple.quarantine" as the extended attribute enabled further search into the problem. I have now stopped pursuing a pure-Java-approach in favour of a combination with a shell script (see answer below).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Short answer

Give it up. Apple has made it next to impossible to elegantly get a Java app to read calendar data.

### Long answer

Since some versions (Catalina?) the directory `~/Library/Calendars/` and all subdirectories (and files therein) are protected by MacOS using extended attributes, namely `com.apple.quarantine`.

It used to be possible to grant applications the specific right to access calendar data using *System Settings* - *Security and Privacy* - *Privacy* - *Calendar*. However, the manual `+`-Button has gone now.

What I will do is use some zsh script to export the desired calendar events to another directory and remove the com.apple.quarantine attribute from there, too.

This is not elegant and leaves the Java world, but for my case, having a Java command line application being started from a designated shell script, it works rather nicely.

Here's what I came up with:

```
#!/bin/zsh

calendars="/Users/yourUserName/Library/Calendars"
target="/Users/yourUserName/some/other/directory/Calendar_Export"

cd ${calendars}

calsource=""
for f in *.calendar
do
    linesFound=`grep -c '<string>Your Calendar Name</string>' ${f}/Info.plist`
    if [[ ${linesFound} -eq 1 ]]
    then
        echo "The relevant calendar resides at " ${f}", copying all events"
        calsource=${calendars}/${f}/Events
    fi
done

if [[ ${calsource} != "" ]]
then
    rm ${target}/*
    cp ${calsource}/* ${target}/
    xattr -d com.apple.quarantine ${target}/*
fi
```